# In Ios ListView automatically scroll to top when Item source is updated in xamarin.forms. Maintain scroll position in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

**I am working on xamarin.forms**. I am facing one issue. I have one ListView. I am giving List object as ItemSource to that listView without any MVVM pattern **(Not follow MVVM)**. List object is updated on Item Tap or Image gesture tap and then I again give itemsource to Listview.

**In ios when I rebind item source to listview, automatically scroll goes to top. So selected item is not visible to user.**

**In Android it works perfect.**

```
<ListView x:Name="lstLeaveNotificationDetails" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" IsVisible="false">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                <ViewCell.View>
                  <StackLayout x:Name="StkForListItems" ClassId="{Binding TapId}">
                    <!--Left Side Orange Color Padding-->
                    <StackLayout Padding="4,0,0,0" BackgroundColor="{Binding BgMainStackColor}">
                      <StackLayout  BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                        <Grid Padding="3" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="0">
                          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                          <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.RowSpan="5" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding CheckSelect}" Aspect="Fill" ClassId="{Binding TapId}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                              <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="img_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                              </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                            </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                          </StackLayout>

                          <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                            <Label Text="{Binding EmpNm}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                          </StackLayout>

                          <Label Text="From" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  TextColor="#B0B0B0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"  FontSize="Small"/>
                          <Label Text="To" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  TextColor="#B0B0B0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"  FontSize="Small"/>
                          <Label Text="Leave Days" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="3"  TextColor="#B0B0B0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start"  FontSize="Small"/>

                          <Label Text="{Binding FromDate}" Grid.Row="2"  Grid.Column="1" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"    FontSize="Small"  />
                          <Label Text="{Binding ToDate}" Grid.Row="2"   Grid.Column="2" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"   FontSize="Small"  />
                          <Label Text="{Binding NoOfLeave}" Grid.Row="2"  Grid.Column="3" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"   FontSize="Small"  />

                          <StackLayout  Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                            <Label Text="Reason" TextColor="#b0b0b0"   FontSize="Small"/>
                          </StackLayout>

                          <StackLayout  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"   Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Reason}" TextColor="Black"   FontSize="Small" />
                          </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                      </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <BoxView  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="3"/>
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnItemTapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                  </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**BackEnd code : On Image Tap I have called following function. Update List object and give it to itemSource**

```
public void ItemSelectionChanged(CachedImage source, StackLayout lstView)
        {
            var objClassId = "";
            if (source != null)
            {
                objClassId = source.ClassId;
            }
            else
            {
                objClassId = lstView.ClassId;
            }

            switch (Key)
            {
                case "LA":
                    if (objLstLeaveLst != null)
                    {
                        LeaveLst objtempLeaveLst = objLstLeaveLst.Find(s => s.TapId.ToString() == objClassId);
                        int index = objLstLeaveLst.IndexOf(objtempLeaveLst);

                        if (objLstLeaveLst[index].CheckSelect.ToString() == AppResources.ImgNotificationSelectionFalse)
                        {
                            objLstLeaveLst[index].CheckSelect = AppResources.ImgNotificationSelectionTrue;
                            List<bool> ImageSelectionFlag = objLstLeaveLst.Select(s => s.CheckSelect.ToString() == "check_sel.png").ToList();
                            ChangeSelectionImage(ImageSelectionFlag);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            objLstLeaveLst[index].CheckSelect = AppResources.ImgNotificationSelectionFalse;
                            imgSelectAll.Source = "check_nor.png";
                            imgSelectAll.ClassId = "false";
                            lblSelectAll.ClassId = "false";
                        }

                        if (objLstLeaveLst[index].BgMainStackColor.Equals(Color.FromHex("#dddddd")))
                        {
                            objLstLeaveLst[index].BgMainStackColor = Color.FromHex("#f15a23");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            objLstLeaveLst[index].BgMainStackColor = Color.FromHex("#dddddd");
                        }

                        lstLeaveNotificationDetails.ItemsSource = null;
                        lstLeaveNotificationDetails.ItemsSource = objLstLeaveLst;
                        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
                        {
                            lstLeaveNotificationDetails.ScrollTo(objtempLeaveLst, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, false);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
}
}
```

To solve this problem I put following Code

```
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
                            {
                                lstLeaveNotificationDetails.ScrollTo(objtempLeaveLst, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, false);
                            }
```

but It does't give me a proper output. How to maintain scroll position in ios. Please help me to do rendering of listView in ios. Don't want to scroll listview when I update Item source.

**I have also tried ObservableCollection but My GUI is not updated on Item tap (Image tap and stack tap).**

Comment: can you share your LeaveLst class please?

Answer (score 1):

The way iOS handles updating the `ListView` and its `ItemsSource` is to update the `ViewSource` underlying the `UITableView`. That, on Xamarin.Forms, or native iOS, is going to clear your entire list, and re-add the items.

The way to accomplish what you're trying to do is to use an `ObservableCollection` **AND** for your model to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

If your model that acts and the `BindingContext` for your individual `Cell` updates a property bound to the view, then it will update that single `Cell` without having to rebind the entire list.

Also, re-applying the `ItemsSource` is an expensive process on the UI, while updating a single cell is cheap!

Here's an example:

The model-

```
public class TodoItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
        }
    }
}
```

Then your view:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding TodoItems}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextCell Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then your code behind:

```
...
MyListView.BindingContext = this;
...
public ObservableCollection<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }
...
// change the text of one item
TodoItems[1].Text = "New Text!";
...
```

Then you'll see the proper cell update the text field without having to update any other items, and also keeping your scroll position!

Answer (score 1):

Use `listView.ScrollTo()` method, see below:

```
 listView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
            { 
     listView.ScrollTo(e.SelectedItem, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, false);               
};
```